# How to create sliding window over signal on matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence of data. So I want to plot that data inside the sliding windows due to windows length.
Help me please.

Actually data is from mean and variance of frames. So I want to plot that mean and variance inside the sliding windows. Also I can't create sliding windows on Matlab.

Comment: is your signal 1D or 2D?

Comment: 1D mean and variance is from image frame , So I plot one by one,

Comment: the term sliding window is misleading, instead the OP wants to only show\treat part of the data he\she already has, i.e. no calculation is needed.

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be,

```
a = randi(100,[1,50]);  % My sequence
win_width = 10;  %Sliding window width
slide_incr = 1;  %Slide for each iteration
numstps = (length(a)-win_width)/slide_incr; %Number of windows
for i = 1:numstps
   mean_win(i) = mean(a(i:i+win_width));  %Calculation for each window
end
plot(mean_win)
```

there may be better ways of doing it..

Comment: FYI you can calculate the mean without a loop by just `mean_win=conv(a,ones(1,win_width)/win_width)`, but that is not what the OP wanted (see comments of other answer)

Comment: For what I've checked, numstps should be added by one and win_width in the for loop should be diminished by one. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've always done it (adapted from code for 2 sliding windows). You can calculate the mean and variance however you'd like.

```
T = 25;                 % Window Size
K = size(data,1) - T;   % Number of repetitions

for i = 1:K    
   window = data(i:i+T-1,:);

   % Mean and Variance Calculations here
   % Plotting here
   % call 'drawnow' for incremental plotting (animation)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly you want to change the **x-axis limits** of the plot. Use [`xlim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) for that, for example:

```
 a=1:10;
 plot(a)
 xmin = 5;
 xmax = 7.6;
 xlim([xmin xmax])
```

or if you want a window of a constant size you can `xlim([xmin xmin+window])` etc...

Comment: I think u got wrong my questions.
I have mean and variance values. I just want to plot them inside the sliding windows

Comment: So I don't understand the question, what is a "sliding window", and why can't you just `plot` the data you have? can you add an example maybe?

Comment: So I want to plot only data which is inside the dashed windows

Comment: I am trying to use that few plotted data later.So urs is just for plotting, do u have another idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24556/discussion-between-bayanaa-and-natan)